# Parallel integration tests handle database counts

Tags: java, spring, junit, integration-testing

I'm running my integration tests in parallel but I have one tests that counts the number of rows in one table but the number can vary depending on many tests have run before that tests runs.

Is there any mechanism in Spring or Junit that would allow me to make sure that when that tests runs that table is clean so that the count would always be 1?

Thanks

Comment: Your tests are running in parallel, it might be difficult to remove data before this test as some other parallel running test can update table. Please give some more information like database & what you exactly mean by running tests parallel,

Comment: Using a PostgreSQL database, and by parallel  I'm using the option setMaxParallelForks on gradle to run multiple tests

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeforeEach` annotation within Junit class:

```
@BeforeEach
void foo() {
    clearDBrows();
}

void clearDBrows(){
//clear db rows 
..
}
```

This is by considering, your other test's wont really care if db table rows get cleared before execution as `@BeforeEach` will get executed for every tests you run.